# Grep command to print a value of an XML Tag

Tags: xml, linux, grep

`"<violation beginline="13" endline="13" begincolumn="19" endcolumn="36" rule="SystemPrintln" ruleset="Java Logging" package="com.test" class="Two" method="violation1Fix" externalInfoUrl="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/rules/java/logging-java.html#SystemPrintln" priority="2">
System.out.print is used1
</violation>`

I have an XML file like this  above -

I want to print the value of "violation" tag and the beginline number for each tag.How can I do it using grep or other linux commands?

I don't want to load the XML file and then print the value as of now because it may have perormance issue.

Comment: grep doesn't understand xml. at best you can use the "context" options to print extra text before/after the matched line. e.g. `grep '<violation' -A 3 whatever.xml`

Answer (score 2):

I won't do it with regex related tool unless you are sure the text format was fixed like that. Any single line break may broke the sed/grep solution.

What you need is xpath to parse the xml and extract things. Under linux you can try `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath '//violation/text()' file.xml
```

will output:

```
System.out.print is used1
```

### update, add the xpath to get the attribute:

```
xmllint --xpath 'number(//violation/@beginline)' file.xml
```

outputs:

```
13
```

if you want the value with attribute name:

```
xmllint --xpath '//violation/@beginline' file.xml
```

outputs:

```
beginline="13"
```

Comment: I was about to suggest xmlstarlet, but this works. Perhaps add `--xpath '//violation/@beginline'` for the other part of the question, though?

Comment: Thanks Kent.Basically I want both -

Comment: System.out.print is used1 and beginline which is 13 ?
how to get both -

Comment: @user3626234 added another line to get the attribute value

Comment: Thanks Wintermute. I tried that and I can get the beginline value.But suppose the case is -<violation> tag count is 3 in XML file and hence my need will be for each violation tag print both -message and beginline. So I think a loop is required?

Comment: @user3626234 xslt is the tool to transform xml into other format. there is tool `xsltproc`

Comment: Hi Kent, for the case where XML file is having number of Violation tags and I need to print the message and beginline for each voilation.What will be the best way to do?Any loops?Your xmllint will print everything but in want in some userfriendly way -message seperated by beginline?

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`

```
grep -oP '(?<=>).*?(?=</violation>)' input.xml && grep -oP '(beginline=").*?(")' input.xml
```

Here is the **output**:

[image]

Comment: I want beginline value also to be printed.this will help the user to get the violation message and beginline number?

Comment: @user3626234 check now

Comment: -I tried the same above command but its not displaying anything..I am using Cygwin

Comment: Is your a.xml same as my above?

Comment: Yes @user3626234 it's same as above xml file cause I just copy-paste the input file from here.

Comment: I can't understand why yours not working, may be you don't have `grep` or even possible due to any other issues like non-bash shell, previous version of `grep`

Comment: When I run your suggested command -its not returining anything.But other grep commands are working.My grep version is 2.5.1 @ Skynet

Comment: My `grep` version is 2.6.3

Comment: I think the problem is with that regular exp as when I give any vale there its working.ex: grep -oP beginline file.xml

Comment: Well @user3626234 I have shown my console output and having same input xml file due to copied from your question so there is nothing I found to failing it.